# Question about continuous but neither open nor closed function on topological space X

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, open-map, closed-map

> Define a function from topological space $\mathrm{X}$ into topological space $\mathrm{X}$, $f:\mathrm{X}\rightarrow \mathrm{X}$ such that $f$ is continuous but neither open nor closed

**My attempt**

I take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and with I defined function $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\tau^{\prime})$,where $\tau$ is discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau^{\prime}$ is indiscrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$.$f$ is given by $f(x)=x$ In this case we have a continuous function since $\tau^{\prime}=\lbrace \mathbb{R}, \emptyset \rbrace$ and $\tau$ is discrete space. But since any set, $\mathrm{U}$,other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ we have neither open nor closed set.

Do I make any mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only problem I see is that I suspect that by $X$, the question refers to a full topological space (i.e. not just the set $X$, but the topology attached as well). So, I think equipping the same set with different topologies, making it a map between *different* topological spaces, might not be in the spirit of the question.

Comment: We are free to choose different topologies

Comment: Then, go forth with my blessing. :)

Comment: I would reckon this to be a function $f:X\to X'$ where $X\neq X'$. You should read $X$ as a notation of a topological space (not of the underlying set). So IMV it is not correct.

Comment: No X are same, we have to choose just one set

Comment: @beingmathematician I think drhab and I share some doubts about this interpretation. Regardless, it might be a good exercise for you to come up with a self-map $f : (X, \tau) \to (X, \tau)$ that is neither open nor closed. Obviously the discrete and indiscrete topologies are poor choices. There are some elementary examples where $(X, \tau)$ is $\Bbb{R}$ under the usual topology.

Comment: I see, I do it by myself what you have left me as an exercise. But I feel refreshed since I learnt I did no mistake

Comment: That is weird. If $X$ only denotes a set then the demand to define a *continuous* function $f:X\to X$ is absurd.

Comment: Why? We can choose topologies differently if we choose discrete as domain then we are done

Comment: By the way X denotes topological space. I forgot to add tihs crucial info

Comment: Follow the advice of Theo given in his third comment, I would say. Then at least things cannot be wrong anymore.

Comment: In his advice I can define some other functions. But I did not understand my fault

Comment: @beingmathematician It's not a fault of your work so much as it's a miscommunication. Your example is fine, provided you can make a map between the same sets with different topologies. Myself and drhab don't believe this is the point of the exercise. Often the full topological space $(X, \tau)$ is shortened just to "$X$", i.e. the same name given to the underlying set of points in the topological space, but the meaning is still $(X, \tau)$. By saying "topological space $X$", we are implicitly including the topology $\tau$ with it.

Comment: @beingmathematician It's confusing, but it saves some notation. As drhab points out, without this assumption that we're talking about a full topological space, it makes no sense to talk about a "continuous" map on the set. When I talk about a continuous function from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$, I *must* be talking about some topology implicitly! When I say "$\Bbb{R}$", what I mean is "the topological space with point set $\Bbb{R}$, and the usual Euclidean topology". So, if I use $\Bbb{R}$ twice in the same sentence, it's assumed that both mean that same topological space, not just a set.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks a lot